# Showing error #1064 in mysql for stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE ( IN in_School_id integer, IN in_leader_score varchar(4))     
BEGIN 
UPDATE chicago_public_schools
SET School_ID=in_School_id 
WHERE Leaders_Score=in_leader_score;
END
```

I'm not able to find the syntax error

Comment: Please publish FULL error message. Also did you set delimiters?